# Нужно сделать органайзер,но теряюсь какой язык выбрать,C++ или Java?

Tags: java, c++

Теряюсь какой язык выбрать,посоветуйте пожалуйста.
Знаю что оба обладают одинаковой мощностью,просто на каком легче будет с 0 изучить выполнить мой проект?Какой более дружелюбный?
с++ раньше изучал,но на уровне консоли,на уровне графического приложения теряюсь
java делал некоторые примеры уже с граф. библиотекой,но саму java знаю плохо
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь если глупость сморожу, с графическими приложениями ни разу не сталкивался,поэтому для меня слегка это всё темновато,но всё когда то в первый раз

Comment: выбирай Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите.

Как язык Java проще и дружелюбнее, чем C++, поэтому учить её будет легче, тем более, у вас есть опыт. С другой стороны, я не впечатлён графическими возможностями у Java. C++ «из коробки» вовсе не имеет графических библиотек, так что вам придётся изучать сторонние фреймворки наподобие Qt или (упаси господи) MFC.

Учтите, что программирование с фреймворками довольно сильно отличается от «обычного» программирования на языке. Вам придётся понять событийную модель поведения программы, научиться отделять уровень отображения от модели, контроллера и бизнес-логики. Так что будьте готовы к тому, что на код своего первого проекта через год вы будете смотреть с иронией.

Кроме того: мне кажется, что умение писать графические программы на Java не очень-то и востребовано, Java занимает нишу серверных приложений (ну и мобильные платформы, но тут свои фреймворки). Qt же, наоборот, популярный и востребованный фреймворк.

Я бы посоветовал ещё обратить внимание на C#/WPF: сочетание современного языка и вменяемого фреймворка. (Учтите, что у WPF довольно высокий порог вхождения.)

Comment: Да,вот на java я как раз с фреймворками ползал,а на с++ вообще их не видел...Просто некоторые элементы которые мне понадобятся,они не стандартные,не просто текстовое поле или чекбокс какой нибудь,поэтому я даже не совсем понимаю,как мне это написать и нужен ли мне для этого фреймворк или самому будет удобнее написать графический элемент?Хотя поидее нужен будет,ибо мне нужен элемент окно,кнопки и прочая самая стандартная лабутень
А чем MFC плох?

Comment: ну тогда может на делфи?

Comment: @KoVadim чтобы сделать приличный гуй на делфи, его (их) нужно знать очень хороша. Такое встречается весьма редко.

Comment: @rusbaron: Ну, смотря какая ваша цель. Поработать с фреймворками и набраться опыта и идей, или выучить что-то для получения работы?

Нестандартных элементов вам по идее не понадобится, хотя кто знает?

MFC плох тем, что в нём ужасно сложно делать нормальные абстракции: он заставляет вас знать детали своего внутреннего устройства (а также детали реализации WinAPI), от которых по-хорошему можно бы абстрагироваться. Иными словами, это чересчур тонкая прослойка над WinAPI (который по сути устарел).

Comment: может взять какой-нибудь фреймворк JavaScript'а и все на нем сделать?

Comment: JavaScript, в отличие от Java — не десктопный язык. Или вы хотите браузерное приложение, с хранением данных на сервере? Вам всё равно придётся писать серверный backend (та же Java, C++ или например node.js).

Comment: @VladD, уверены что "JavaScript, в отличие от Java — не десктопный язык"?

Все-таки он стал очень популярен. Я поинтересовался у гугла и вот за 10 минут нарыл, что оказывается есть [десктопный JS](http://www.tidesdk.org/).

IMHO интересная штука. Что думаете?

Comment: да, интересная штука. на днях присмотрюсь к ней повнимательнее.

Comment: @avp: это да, но всё же это пока дикая экзотика. То есть формально говоря, есть, но я бы пока не ставил на это, разве что поиграться.

Ну и кроме того, писать приложение с несколькими layer'ами на языке без строгого контроля типов несколько стрёмно, не находите?

Comment: @VladD, ну, наверное поиграться. 

Или Вы считаете, что кто-то сейчас может запусить в качестве серьезного проекта десктопный органайзер?

Comment: @avp: альтернативой «поиграться» я бы видел «приобрести опыт для резюме». Конечно, серьёзным проектом такое назвать нельзя.

Comment: вы наверное будете смеятся,но я хочу сделать себе прогу,которая просто облегчит мне мою работу и самообразование,заодно во время создания и язык выучу.Я примерно себе его начертил,этот проект и нестандартные элементы мне 100% понадобятся.

Comment: JS в смысле JS + C++ как в qt или просто JS через браузер?

Comment: @rusbaron, я так понял, что "standalone" JS, просто десктопный интерпретатор + соответствующий API для работы с файлами (про браузер же никаких слов не видел).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы для этих целей использовал С++ вместе с Qt или gtk. Оба кроссплатформенны.